# Sum of i.i.d. variables can be bounded a.s.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are i.i.d. random variables where $E[X_n] = 0$ for all $n \geq 1$. Then there is $K > 0$ such that $P(|X_1 + \cdots + X_n| \leq K \text{ i.o.}) = 1$.

I thought we could use contradiction. Say for all $K > 0$ we get that $$P(|X_1 + \cdots + X_n| \leq K \text{ i.o.}) < 1,$$ then $$0 < P(|X_1 + \cdots + X_n| > K \text{ for large n}) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} P(|X_1 + \cdots + X_n| > K) \\
\leq \frac{1}{K} \liminf_{n \to \infty} E(|X_1 + \cdots + X_n|).$$ If I could bound the limit we are done since $K \to 0$ finishes the contradiction. But I do not think we can calculate this easily.

Edit: Do I need another condition on my $X_n$?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can choose any $K > 0$. This is a consequence of the Chung Fuchs Theorem, which states that the random walk that you consider returns to any given neighborhood of zero infinitely often, see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chung%E2%80%93Fuchs_theorem